# How to use fancyimpute on PyCharm

Tags: python, anaconda, data-science, jetbrains-ide

I've installed `fancyimpute` on Anaconda with `pip install fancyimpute` through the Anaconda terminal but I use PyCharm with Anaconda as its interpreter.  I couldn't find a way to use `fancyimpute` in PyCharm.  I searched for it through `Settings/Project Interpreter/Available Packages` but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
python -m pip install fancyimpute
```

this will take you pycharm default python interpreter and install the package in the python site package. you will be able to see this package in your project

Comment: on which terminal?

Comment: pycharm terminal

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  I've accepted and upvoted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?